# How can I update application in kiosk mode and screen pin enabled device?

Tags: android, kiosk, kiosk-mode, android-screen-pinning

I have setup one application on device for my customer with screen pin (using kiosk mode).
I want to update application remotely for that I am doing below things.

1. Uploading apk on my server.
2. I have button in my application which download the apk and ask for installing the apk.
3. After installing my application screen pin stoped due which user can access the whole tablet. (this we don't want).

I don't know whether this is correct way of updating the app or not as kiosk/screen pinning is new for us.

My customer do not want to use third party provider. So we have to use our server only.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the [Android Management API](https://developers.google.com/android/management/), it allows to set an app in kiosk mode, control the time of updates (with [SystemUpdate](https://developers.google.com/android/management/reference/rest/v1/enterprises.policies#systemupdate)) and it automatically puts the app back in kiosk mode once the update is complete.